# How to get ng-map marker position after dragend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I'm using ng-map for Angularjs, I'm using the following code to get marker position after drag event

```
<div class="mapWrap"   data-tap-disabled="true">

        <map center="43.07493,-89.381388" zoom="4"> 

          <marker draggable=true position="{{pos.lat}},{{pos.lng}}" 
          on-dragend="getCurrentLocation()"></marker>    
        </map>
```

```
$scope.getCurrentLocation = function(){

     $scope.pos = this.getPosition();
     concole.log($scope.pos.lat() +' '+ $scope.pos.lng());
}
```

But its not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `on-dragend` represent a valid event for ng-map? and if so what's the alternative?

Comment: Wouldn't the docs tell you that?

Comment: Got it from another question not from the docs ? here is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34152457/ng-map-get-address-after-dragging-marker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get it from the event of on-dragend:

```
$scope.getCurrentlocation = function(e) {
    $scope.address.lat = e.latLng.lat();
    $scope.address.lng = e.latLng.lng();
};
```

At least this works for me.

Comment: It did not work for me. Can you also provide the `HTML5` for that?

Comment: i used the markup from the original question. make sure you set draggable attribute to true